# How to code multiple column in order and the remove the duplicated data in tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have 20 columns but a sample of these data are as follows:

```
A1  A2  A3
So,Smith    Amo, Bazse  Arzo, Ghas
Jo, Man Amo, Bazse  Imran, Maz
So,Smith    Hosh,Golab  Imran, Maz
Jo, Man Jo, Man Imran, Maz
Rose,Moli   Niss, Peak  Arzo, Ghas
Goli,Gouzo  Ebi,Sat Imran, Maz
Jo, Man Ebi,Sat Imran, Maz
Rose,Moli   Niss, Peak  Arzo, Ghas
Goli,Gouzo  Jo, Man Arzo, Ghas
```

I want to code each person within each column starting from 1. So I will get the following results:

```
A1A A2A A3A
1   5   10
2   5   11
1   6   11
2   7   11
3   8   10
4   9   11
2   9   11
3   8   10
4   7   10
```

I have used the following codes:

```
df$A1A <- as.integer(as.factor(df$A1))
df$A2A <- as.integer(as.factor(df$A2)) + max(df$A1A)
df$A3A <- as.integer(as.factor(df$A3)) + max(df$A2A)
```

But sometimes I get wrong codes, especially when the number of columns is increased

finally, I want to get the following table.

```html
A1      C1    A2        C2    A3       C3
So,Smith   1   Amo, Bazse 5    Arzo, Ghas 10
Jo, Man    2   Hosh,Golab 6   Imran, Maz 11
Rose,Moli   3   Jo, Man     7  
Goli,Gouzo 4   Niss, Peak 8  
                Ebi,Sat     9
```

I have used the following code to remove duplicates, but it does not work.

```
df[!duplicated(df[c(1:3)]),]
```

Can we do it in R especially using a robust code?

Comment: The second table is not clear.  Pleaee format it

Comment: Please use `dput`, I can't clearly identify the column.  From what I see, 'C1' is empty

Comment: You can check my update,  It seems to be the expected output for seecond table

Comment: Ok, I think I am done with this.  I showed the output similar to the one you showed

Comment: I did tested couple of times and it is working fine for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option where we loop through the column, convert it to index by `match`ing the values with the `unique` values in that column ('m1'), get the `colMaxs` (from `matrixStats`), use that to add with the columns of 'm1' starting from 2nd column

```
m1 <- sapply(df1, function(x) match(x, unique(x)))
library(matrixStats)
v1 <- colMaxs(m1)
#or in base R
# v1 <- apply(m1, 2, max)
m1[,-1] <- m1[,-1] + cumsum(v1[-length(v1)])[col(m1[,-1])]
m1
#      A1 A2 A3
# [1,]  1  5 10
# [2,]  2  5 11
# [3,]  1  6 11
# [4,]  2  7 11
# [5,]  3  8 10
# [6,]  4  9 11
# [7,]  2  9 11
# [8,]  3  8 10
# [9,]  4  7 10
```

---

If we want to get the second dataset

```
library(rowr)
out <- do.call(cbind.fill, c(Map(function(x, y)
      data.frame(col1 = x, col2 = unique(y)), 
        lapply(df1, unique), split(m1, col(m1))), fill = NA))
names(out) <- c(rbind(names(df1), paste0("C", seq_along(df1))))
out
#          A1   C1         A2 C2         A3   C3
#1   So,Smith    1 Amo, Bazse  5 Arzo, Ghas   10
#2    Jo, Man    2 Hosh,Golab  6 Imran, Maz   11
#3  Rose,Moli    3    Jo, Man  7       <NA> <NA>
#4 Goli,Gouzo    4 Niss, Peak  8       <NA> <NA>
#5       <NA> <NA>    Ebi,Sat  9       <NA> <NA>
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A1 = c("So,Smith", "Jo, Man", "So,Smith", "Jo, Man", 
"Rose,Moli", "Goli,Gouzo", "Jo, Man", "Rose,Moli", "Goli,Gouzo"
), A2 = c("Amo, Bazse", "Amo, Bazse", "Hosh,Golab", "Jo, Man", 
"Niss, Peak", "Ebi,Sat", "Ebi,Sat", "Niss, Peak", "Jo, Man"), 
    A3 = c("Arzo, Ghas", "Imran, Maz", "Imran, Maz", "Imran, Maz", 
    "Arzo, Ghas", "Imran, Maz", "Imran, Maz", "Arzo, Ghas", "Arzo, Ghas"
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: @User20100 I think your second output is a mess. We don't know what data type it is. If the length of each column is not the same, it cannot be a data frame or a matrix. So what do you want?

Comment: @User20100 Can you format your table 2 better before you make any demand?

Comment: Thank you @akrun

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `lapply` and `for-loop`.

```
dat2[] <- lapply(dat2, function(x) as.integer(factor(x, levels = unique(x))))

for (i in 1:ncol(dat2)){
  if (i > 1){
    dat2[i] <- dat2[i] + max(dat2[i - 1])
  }
}

dat2
#   A1 A2 A3
# 1  1  5 10
# 2  2  5 11
# 3  1  6 11
# 4  2  7 11
# 5  3  8 10
# 6  4  9 11
# 7  2  9 11
# 8  3  8 10
# 9  4  7 10
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "A1    A2  A3
'So,Smith'  'Amo, Bazse'    'Arzo, Ghas'
'Jo, Man'   'Amo, Bazse'    'Imran, Maz'
'So,Smith'  'Hosh,Golab'    'Imran, Maz'
'Jo, Man'   'Jo, Man'   'Imran, Maz'
'Rose,Moli' 'Niss, Peak'    'Arzo, Ghas'
'Goli,Gouzo'    'Ebi,Sat'   'Imran, Maz'
'Jo, Man'   'Ebi,Sat'   'Imran, Maz'
'Rose,Moli' 'Niss, Peak'    'Arzo, Ghas'
'Goli,Gouzo'    'Jo, Man'   'Arzo, Ghas'",
stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```